# WP-Polls set IP limit at 2

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, polling

I'm using [wp-polls](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-polls/) and need to limit the number of votes per IP. Although this is usually set at 1 by default, I need to limit the number of votes per IP to 2.

I've been reading documentation, playing with the plugin code, and looking around on google and SO and can't seem to find the proper method.

- I've considered using cookies, but these are harder to catch since I could just as well empty my cookies and voilà, it's done.
- I need a limit because I don't want people to vote endlessly
- Looking at the database, I imagine this has something to do with the `pollip_ip` field (from the `(prefix)_pollsip`) table, but not being familiar with editing WP Plugins, this is as far I as I got to go.

**As a reference, here is some failed code**

wp-polls.php, line 1323

```
// original code
// if($check_voted == 0) { 


// proposed by @birgire
if( $check_voted == 0 || ( is_array( $check_voted ) && 2 >= count( $check_voted ) ) ) {
```

wp-polls.php, line 1323

```
// original code
// if($check_voted == 0) { 


// alternative of code proposed by @birgire
if( ($check_voted == 0) || count($check_voted) <= 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't see any available filters for this, when I skimmed through the plugin source.

I wonder if it would work, if you replace line [#1323](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-polls/trunk/wp-polls.php#L1323) of the `wp-polls.php` file:

```
 if($check_voted == 0) {
```

with:

```
 if( $check_voted == 0 
     || ( is_array( $check_voted ) && 2 >= count( $check_voted ) ) ) {
```

to limit the number of votes per IP to 2.

**Additionally:**

Replace line [#140](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-polls/trunk/wp-polls.php#L140) with:

```
if( !is_array($check_voted) && intval($check_voted) > 0  
     || (is_array($check_voted) && sizeof($check_voted) > 1)
     || ($poll_active == 0 && $poll_close == 1)) {
```

But I don't recommend in general to modify plugin files, since it will be restored in the next plugin update.

*Sidenote:* The plugin is not using the recommended `$wpdb->prepare()` when preparing the SQL for `$wpdb->query()`.

Comment: The above answer does seem plausible, but unlikely as no page content loads (view source is empty!) when trying this code. This being said, I will give you half a point for the recommendation. I do understand that this is not optimal, but it is a client requirement and this is annoying me.

Comment: Sounds like a PHP syntax error, do you have `WP_DEBUG` activated ?

Comment: Yes, I do have WP_DEBUG activated in my wp-config

Comment: ok, so you get a white screen and no error messages? And you get the site back when you revert the changes?

Comment: I installed the plugin and the above changes allows me to vote 2 times per IP - but I only tested it for a single IP ;-)

Comment: Get, line 140 was the missing key. I've edited the code as to correct a double `||` you had entered on your last line. It is now functional, thank you !